# What is the difference between `GlobalConsensus` (tuple struct with NetworkId) and `NetworkId` (be used via AccountId32) in XCM `MultiLocation`?

Tags: xcm

XCM version: 3

I'm learing XCM. I want to specify a Polkadot account by `MultiLocation` when within a parachain on Polkadot like Statemint, I know it can be specified with `ParentThen(X1(AccountId32)).into`.

But are the other two ways below correct? What is the difference between the three of them?

Option 1: Use `NetworkId` to sepcify Polkadot in `GlobalConsensus`.

```
MultiLocation { 
   parents: 0,
   interior: X2(GlobalConsensus(Polkadot), AccountId32 { network: None, id: [...] }) 
}
```

Option 2: Use `NetworkId` to specify Polkadot in `AccountId32`.

```
MultiLocation {
   parents: 0,
   interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: Some(Polkadot), id: [...] }) 
}
```

I know this question may be similar to [another](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1744/how-to-use-multilocation-in-xcm-to-express-an-account-address-of-ethereum) , but the focus of that question may be Ethereum, here I want to know what is the difference between these two ways of specifying `NetworkId` and when should I use which?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at these three `MultiLocation` values, assuming we have a 32-byte account ID `id`:

#### 1. `(Parent, AccountId32 { network: None, id }).into()`

This is more idiomatic, but otherwise exactly equal to the first suggestion you made:

```
ParentThen(X1(AccountId32 { network: None, id })).into()
```

It means "the 32-byte account of identity `id` as interpreted within the context of the parent's consensus system", with an extra note that `id` (i.e. that 32-byte value) should not be considered associated with a particular network.

An example of using this would be when referring to a Relay-chain account from within a parachain's logic. The `Parent` would take it "up" into the Relay-chain location and then the `AccountId32` would bring it "down" into an account on it.

#### 2. `(Polkadot, AccountId32 { network: None, id }).into()`

This is more idiomatic, but otherwise exactly equal to the second suggestion you made:

```
MultiLocation {
  parents: 0,
  interior: X2(
    GlobalConsensus(Polkadot),
    AccountId32 { network: None, id }
  )
}
```

It means "the 32-byte account of identity `id` as interpreted within the context of the Polkadot network which itself should be found within the local consensus system", with an extra note that `id` (i.e. that 32-byte value) should not be considered associated with a particular network.

Since no real consensus system contains the Polkadot network, this location doesn't make any sense.

The corresponding value of type `InteriorMultiLocation` is:

```
MultiLocation::from((Polkadot, AccountId32 { network: None, id }))
```

This does have a meaning: being an `InteriorMultiLocation` it never contains `Parent`s and thus is used to represent *Universal* locations, i.e. locations to be interpreted within the hypothetical *Universal Consensus* defined as the parent of all top-level consensus systems.

Used in this way, the value would refer to the account `id` on the Polkadot Relay-chain, much like in the example for (1).

#### 3. `AccountId32 { network: Some(Polkadot), id }.into()`

This is more idiomatic, but otherwise exactly equal to the third suggestion you made:

```
MultiLocation {
  parents: 0,
  interior: X1(
    AccountId32 { network: Some(Polkadot), id }
  )
}
```

This means "the 32-byte account of identity `id` as interpreted within the context of the local consensus system", with an extra note that `id` (i.e. that 32-byte value) should be considered strictly associated with the Polkadot network, as opposed to e.g. Kusama.

In general, specifying the `network` in an `AccountId32` is not done since there is rarely a need to make a strict association between a particular account and a network. Generally an account is considered "compatible" if the public key (i.e. `id`) is the same length as account IDs on the local chain.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at the docs on `GlobalConsensus`:

```
/// A global network capable of externalizing its own consensus. This is not generally
/// meaningful outside of the universal level.
```

The only chance where a `MultiLocation` mentions something that is "at the universal level" would be bridges, hence outside of the application of bridges, we don't really use the `GlobalConsensus` junction all that much. So if the XCM in question originates from Kusama and attempts to send an XCM over to Polkadot via a bridge, then I would expect to see a `GlobalConsensus` junction, in order to instruct the bridge to relay it to the correct destination.

However, in most cases, the `MultiLocation` is referring to a location that is *local*, i.e. it does not exist outside of the local consensus system and doesn't require reaching out to the universal consensus level, and so most of the time, one does not even need to specify exactly *which* `NetworkId` to use in the `id` field of `AccountId32` -- a simple `None` would already suffice (though it would still work if `Polkadot` is specified, provided that the local consensus system is indeed Polkadot). Note also that the account ID is not an SS58 address, and so no matter which parachain your source or destination is, the account ID would still stay the same, as an SS58 address can always be derived from an `AccountId32`.